# Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by $y = ln x$, $y = 0$, $x = 2$ about the $x$-axis

Tags: integration, logarithms, volume

I have the problem: Assuming $y = ln(x)$, and $y = 0$, find the volume bound by these two lines and the point $x = 2$ if the area were rotated around the $x$-axis.

I ended up with $2\pi\int_1^2 \ln(x) dx $

I would like to know if this is the correct way to set this problem up given the bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is the finite region bounded by the *lines* $y=0$, $x=2$, and the curve $y=\ln x$, and we are rotating about the $x$-axis, then the volume is
$$\int_1^2 \pi(\ln x)^2\,dx.$$
For take a slice of the solid at $x$. Then the radius of cross-section is $y$, that is, $\ln x$, so the area of cross-section is $\pi(\ln x)^2$.

**Remark:** If you want to use cylindrical shells instead, then we get the expression
$$\int_0^{\ln 2}2\pi y(2-e^y)\,dy$$
for the volume.

Comment: I have a question about the lower limit of integration though. Why is it 0? Would it not be 1 since we know that $\ln(1) = 0$?